# Package failing to pass R CMD check 'package <mypackage> is not installed for arch =i386', any reason why this would happen?

Tags: r

Any reason why my package would say this? I have written C++ files that are included with the package, if that provides context. There is no other error info that comes along with this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hunch: You are on Windows (or another OS which by default runs multi-arch like OS X), you are trying to run `R CMD check` and it fails to check on one of its two sub-architectures for lack of a package you depend upon.

Also note that `R CMD check --no-multiarch ...` is likely to help you here.

Comment: will that impact the functionality of my package on 32-bit systems?